# Delete First 3 Rows & Last 3 Rows in Target Table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I want to delete first 3 rows and last 3 rows in the table.But using single query for deleting data from the table.I am using oracle 10g. Please give me solution for oracle 10g.

And my table is like:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM EMP;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                    10

14 rows selected.

I want output like this.

target
------

7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400         30
7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                    30
7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10
7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20
7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10
7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0         30
7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no *first 3 and last 3* without specifying an ordering. also, what was your attempt in solving this?

Comment: Are you wanting to order by the `EMPNO`?  You don't have an `ORDER BY` in the query, and without one specified the resulting order (and thus, the top 3 and bottom 3 records) are not guaranteed.

Comment: Can "first"  and "last" be determined by order of employee number?

Comment: @Gyanendra Kumar: You haven't answered the question: what is first and last for you? Then: Do you want to *select* rows or *delete* rows. Then again: Don't you think you should try yourself first and then only come here in case you get stuck somewehere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the ordering is based on `EMPNO`, then you can do:

```
delete from emp
   where emp.empno in (select empno
                       from (select empno,
                                    row_number() over (order by empno) as seqnum_asc,
                                    row_number() over (order by empno desc) as seqnum_desc
                             from emp
                            ) e
                        where seqnum_asc <= 3 or seqnum_sec <= 3
                       );
```

Comment: I am glad, you've come up with a solution. I was already afraid Gyanendra would have to do his homework himself ;-)

Comment: I tried a lot of time.I deleted first 3 rows but i didn't get it solution for how to delete last 3 rows.Thanks @Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM  YourTable
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM YourTable ORDER BY ID ASC
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM YourTable ORDER BY ID DESC
)
```

This will select the first 3 and the last 3 registers from your table considering the ID`s. But be sure that no one has modified the table while you were coding, because you may delete registers that you do not want to.

Comment: Oracle 10g has no `TOP`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries for retrieving first three and last three rows. The top level statement can delete them. You need something that defines the order like the employee number.

```
DELETE FROM EMP
WHERE EMPNO IN (
  SELECT EMPNO
  FROM (
    SELECT EMPNO
    FROM EMP
    ORDER BY EMPNO ASC
  ) 
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 3
) OR EMPNO IN (
  SELECT EMPNO
  FROM (
    SELECT EMPNO
    FROM EMP
    ORDER BY EMPNO DESC
  ) 
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 3
)
```

Comment: Oracle 10g has no `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: I found it here: docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html. Isn't it about Oracle 10g?

Comment: No, this seems to be about a DBMS called Java DB.

Comment: Answer changed to use ROWNUM instead of FETCH FIRST.